# AWS says there's "No module named pipenv"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk and am using `requirements.txt` to install any dependencies. The `requirements.txt` and `local-requirements.txt` is identical and this web app works local.

When I try to deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk (using `eb deploy`), it fails and health is severe. The error given is

```
Error: fail to install dependencies with Pipfile file with error 
Command /bin/sh -c python3 -m pipenv install --skip-lock failed with error exit status 1.
Stderr:/bin/python3: No module named pipenv
```

I'm not sure how to get pipenv working with Elastic Beanstalk as I have `--skip-lock` and it works locally

Comment: In my case had to use `pip3 install pipenv`, as opposed to `pip install pipenv`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was because my Pipenv used Python 3.7 and my environment was 3.8 so I made my environment 3.7 and it's all good!

Answer (score 0):

I had to

```
pip uninstall pipenv
```

Then (notice `pip3`)

```
pip3 install pipenv
```